How to Implement Stream on RPC Functions for Flutter Supabase?
I'm currently working on a Flutter project using Supabase as the backend. I'm trying to implement a stream on RPC (Remote Procedure Call) functions to receive real-time updates, but I'm facing issues.
I've tried using the asStream() method, but it doesn't seem to stream changes as expected. Can someone guide me on how to properly implement streaming on RPC functions in Flutter Supabase to receive real-time updates? Any help or code examples would be appreciated.
Issue: Its working like future. If there is a change in DB it doesn't update UI or even print('Yes')
Thank you!
Here the code
Stream readSteam() {
    return supabase
        .rpc(
          'read_guest_count',
          params: {
            'param_user_id': currentUuid,
          },
        )
        .asStream()
        .doOnDone(
          () => print('Yes'),
        );
  }

Widget
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: readSteam(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        // While waiting for data, display a loading indicator or placeholder
                        return Text(
                          'Loading...',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        // If there's an error with the stream, display an error message
                        return Text(
                          'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                        );
                      } else {
                        // If the stream has data, display the data in the Text widget
                        final List<dynamic>? count =
                            snapshot.data as List<dynamic>?;

                        int totalGuests =
                            count![0]['total_guests'];
                        return Text(
                          '$totalGuests',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  )


so where are you using readSteam() method?

Greeting, I've made some modifications to the code. Specifically, I've incorporated the readStream() method within a StreamBuilder. Sorry for previous mistake. @pskink

It's working like a future. If there is a change in DB it doesn't update UI or even print('Yes')

first remove that .doOnDone(() => print('Yes')) and add print(snapshot) before the line if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) { , what do you see on the logs?

I managed to print the data retrieved from the database using snapshot.data. @pskink

here is a suggestion for u ..
Stream<dynamic> readStream() {
  return supabase
      .rpc(
        'read_guest_count',
        params: {
          'param_user_id': currentUuid,
        },
      )
      .asStream();
}

    SteamBuilder(
     stream: readStream(),
    builder:(context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
   
     return Text(
     'Loading...',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                            );
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                         
                            return Text(
                              'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                            );
                          } else {
    final data = snapshot.data;
    reutrn Text(
    '$data',
    style:TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
    );
    }
    },
    )

try this i am not a expert hope it will help

Streaming realtime updates from a rpc function in Supabase is simply impossible. Currently in Supabase, you can only listen to realtime updates on a single table. That is the limitation.
Depending on what you are trying to do, there is always a workaround to achieve it with how Supabase works. If you can share more of your particular use case, and what exactly you are trying to achieve, I can guide you to a solution that might work.

I'm currently utilizing RPC to fetch data from three different tables in a single query: guests, balcony_guest, and vip_guest. Using RPC makes it straightforward to retrieve data from all these tables and return it based on specific conditions. However, I now require real-time updates to track ticket sales and show availability.
How I can implement real-time updates for this scenario? I want to continuously monitor changes in the number of tickets sold across these tables to reflect the latest availability. @dshukertjr

@RajA You can just set three different real-time listeners.
